# when does the function been declared and assigned in js?

Tags: javascript, scope

Example:

```
ouch(); //"TypeError: ouch is not a function
var ouch= function(){
  console.log("ouch");
};
```

the code above cannot work, because the function ouch is declared after calling.
while in another way. we bind ouch function in a click callback, then it can work!

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
  ouch(); // "ouch"
});
var ouch= function(){
  console.log("ouch");
};
```

Can you explain why we can call ouch like this. Is ouch already been declared and assigned. If so, when does the engine make the declared and assigned?

Comment: call function when dom is ready, or body **onload** it will work.

Comment: how the click event can change the scope?

Comment: `<body onload='ouch()'>` or `$(document).ready(function(){  /*ouch();*/});`